# DMARC and DKIM alignment with multiple DKIM signatures

Tags: dkim, dmarc, alignment

If an email contains multiple DKIM signatures as it's forwarded, how does DMARC process the DKIM alignment check?

Does ANY passing DKIM signature d= parameter have to match Header From?

or

Does the first (or last) DKIM signature d= parameter have to match Header From?

or

Does the single DKIM as indicated in the "Authentication-Results" have to pass (which may always be the last?)?

This is NOT a question of relaxed vs. strict.

Thank you!

Comment: were you ever able to find the answer to this question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to DMARC specification: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7489

> Note that a single email can contain multiple DKIM signatures, and it
> is considered to be a DMARC "pass" if any DKIM signature is aligned
> and verifies.

Answer (score 4):

If there are multiple DKIM signatures, only one of them must align for DKIM alignment to be valid according to https://mxtoolbox.com/problem/dkim/dkim-signature-alignment